# Why is the str() data type not making the input into a string variable?

Tags: python, string

```
cement = str(input("Do you want premium cement or standard cement? "))
print(cement)
```

It works for the choice of cement but also for a number.

When I try an input with numbers the program doesn't close and tells me that an integer is wrong. Instead, it takes the number as a string but I don't want it to.

Is there any way I can fix this?

Comment: btw your use of `str()` is redundant since `input()` always returns a `str`

Comment: @quamrana is there any way i can make an input of a number stop the program?

Comment: You could evaluate `cement.isnumeric()` and exit if that is `True`. On the other hand, it is probably better to just test if the input is one of the valid inputs and not worry about if the invalid input is numeric or some other type of nonsense.

Comment: A string can contain any characters, even numbers. Entering numbers doesn't make it not a string.

Comment: What are you even asking?

Comment: What part tells you that an integer is wrong? You didn't post that.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for what you need:

```
cement = str(input("Do you want premium cement or standard cement? "))
if (any(char.isdigit() for char in cement)) == True:
    exit()
else:
    print(cement)
```

When you enter any sentence containing a number such as `1a` or `1` it exits the program.

Hope this helps